# CVS related folder case issue

Tags: linux, windows, cvs

this is related to cvs,  somehow checked in two folders with same names but different names. Upon checking out only uppercase get checkout as windows is case insensitive. So deleted the folders in cvs.And checked in again one folder with small cases. Upon checking it out it still checks out in a folder named in uppercase. On linux it checks out the small case folder. Its confusing. Do i need to erase an entry in some of the cvs's administrative files.

Comment: Edit: Two Folders with same names and different cases.

Comment: Do use the button [edit] if you are adding more info.

Comment: If one of the answers is the correct answer to your question, please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark. This gives the answerer points and StackOverflow is points- and reputation-based. :-) And if not, a follow up on what you found the correct answer to be is always useful.

Comment: Had to remove the folders from the cvs machine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, if you have root access on the server, I would suggest renaming one of these folders on the server to something case-insensitively-unique.

Client-side operations (i.e. delete the files within that folder, and then re-add then in a better-named folder) will only go so far as a cvs checkout even with `-P` will just create the empty folder and then delete it. On Windows, I worry that the behaviour would still be unpredictable even after the client-side fix.

Of course always be careful of operations on the server. If there are lots of people working on this project, you may want to coordinate with them and make sure everybody can successfully update any existing workspaces after this.